# How to get app-ads.txt url for appstore in google admob?

Tags: admob, app-store-connect

I realized that my google admob account for appstore doesn't have **App-ads.txt URL**

How do I get it ?

In my playstore I simple add the app-ads link at :
=> Store settings
=> Store Listing contact details
=> Website

Please check my screenshot :
[image]

Comment: is same link is updated on marketing url on iTunes? Your website should be listed on iTunes section to be validated by admob - ref https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9363762?hl=en

Comment: @AmodGokhale Yeah, thank you. That's on marketing url in appstore. I miss it in the documentation

Comment: @AmodGokhale Could you reply as an answer ? I will mark as accept answer. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For Apple App Store: Add your developer website in the marketing URL
> field of your store listing.
>
> For Google Play: Add the website URL in the contact information of
> your app listing:

For developer website update on Apple App store - need to publish an update to app. Hope they change this policy in future.

Reference - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9363762?hl=en

To troubleshoot any issues with apps-ads.txt  - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9776740